# re-plug required to get usb device link established

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, kernel

I'm having a builddroot assembled busybox distribution running on my micro. 
It all works well so far but I realized one thing. When I boot my box up and 
I do an lsusb I see this:

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:14ac Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x
```

Composite Device
and I have following links:

```
ttyUSB0  ttyUSB1  ttyUSB2  ttyUSB3
```

buyt none of those links seem to go to Device 0004 but if I replug the 
CP210x device, I get this:

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:14ac Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x
```

Composite Device
and these links:

```
ttyUSB0  ttyUSB1  ttyUSB2  ttyUSB3  ttyUSB4
```

and now ttyUSB4 is linking to my Device 005 why do I need to replug my 
device in order to get a working symlink? That's not what I want? :(
How can I fix this? The cp210x module is compiled into the kernel (not 
attached as a separate module) - any suggestions?

Comment: Output of `dmesg` could help.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between the existence of nodes in /dev, and kernel drivers which will respond at those major/minor numbers.  Device nodes would be created by something in userspace, which may in your setup only be getting triggered by a replug event, even if the kernel driver was already usable before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This for some reason just stop happening probably due to the fact that we're only using one usb device now. Inodes would have been a solution but got never implemented in our system.